# actual argument long cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, algorithm

The code is giving me an error, I can't explain why this is happening. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

It says the long cannot be converted to int, but when I switch an int to a long, I can't add x + multx with a long.

```
class MultCalc {
    public static int multx(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 0) return 0;
        if (y == 0) return 0;
        else return x + multx(x, y - 1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long x = 77777;
        long y = 1234;
        MultCalc calc = new MultCalc();
        long ans = calc.multx(x, y);
        System.out.println(x + " times " + y + " equals " + ans);
    }
}
```

ERROR that is giving me.

```
error: method multx in class MultCalc cannot be applied to given types;
      long ans = calc.multx(x, y);
                     ^
  required: int,int
  found: long,long
  reason: actual argument long cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
1 error
```

Comment: you need to pass in an int, in your main function you declared x and y as long. try casting as integer or defining x and y as int.

Answer (score 4):

The method signature is

```
 multx(int x, int y)
```

And this is called with two `long`s. a `long` cannot be implicitly converted to an `int` in this case.

You either have to create another method to accept `long` parameters or cast the `long` parameters to `int`. Casting may cause data loss.

See *2.4.6. Type Conversions* and the table *Table 2-4. Java Primitive Type Conversions* in [Primitive Data Types](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_04.htm):

> ```
> Convert     Convert To:
> From:       boolean    byte    short    char    int    long    float    double
> boolean      -         N         N        N       N     N        N         N
> byte         N         -         Y        C       Y     Y        Y         Y
> short        N         C         -        C       Y     Y        Y         Y
> char         N         C         C        -       Y     Y        Y         Y
> int          N         C         C        C       -     Y        Y*        Y
> long         N         C         C        C       C     -        Y*        Y*
> float        N         C         C        C       C     C        -         Y
> double       N         C         C        C       C     C        C         -
> ```
>
> N: the conversion cannot be performed.
>   C: means that the conversion
>   is a narrowing conversion and requires an explicit cast.
>   Y: the conversion is a widening conversion and is therefore performed
>   automatically and implicitly by Java
>   Y*: means that the conversion is
>   an automatic widening conversion, but that some of the least
>   significant digits of the value may be lost by the conversion. This
>   can happen when converting an `int` or `long` to a `float` or `double`. The
>   floating-point types have a larger range than the integer types, so
>   any `int` or `long` can be represented by a `float` or `double`. However, the
>   floating-point types are approximations of numbers and cannot always
>   hold as many significant digits as the integer types.

See also [Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1), the `long` type can store values from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, inclusive. If you want to convert a `long` to an `int` you have to do an explicit cast because the `int` type can store values only from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, inclusive. So if the value stored in the `long` variable is too big, information can be lost. It's called [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

You can do the cast directly in the method call:

```
long ans = calc.multx((int)x, (int)y);
```

The method `multx` returns an `int` value, but you can store it into a `long` whitout explicit cast because there is no risk of information loss. 
It's called [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3437460 I don't know why. I think my answer is correct. This question is related to the problem https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni The down voter could have at least stated why he down voted it. Anyway, I have already +1 to neutralize the down vote. I also had several unjustified down votes in some posts in the past.

Comment: @user3437460 Thanks, it helps me to believe that SO is a good place to cooperate.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni You are welcome. I would say, we are not always that lucky to someone to help you ;P